# Multiple similar named variables in loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables

I have multiple variables called lets say:

```
var1
var2
var3
...
var100
```

and want to assign same function to all of them, but with different arguments (the variable's "number"), like this:

```
var1 = myFunction(1);
var2 = myFunction(2);
var3 = myFunction(3);
...
var100 = myFunction(100);
```

Is it possible to do this with *for* loop, or do I have to do it manually? I can use jQuery.

Or would it be better to just use arrays? If so, is it even possible to do it the way I asked?

Comment: Arrays. You can do it the way you ask but it is not good and needlessly complicated. Arrays are definitely the tool here. You can do it with a simple `var arr = []; for(var i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) arr.push(myFunction(i));`

Comment: Start by not using "multiple variables". With the appropriate data structure, a loop will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are the correct approach here.
For example, in ES5:

```
var array = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  array.push(myFunction(i));
}
```

or in ES6:

```
Array.from({length: 100}, (_, i) => myFunction(i));
```

or

```
[...Array(100)].map((_, i) => myFunction(i));
```

The ES5 example pushes them one by one, the ES6 examples use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 1):

you can make them part of a bigger object check the following sample:

```
function myFunction (i) {
  // your logic here
  return i; 
}
// create array of length 100
var varsArray = Array.from({length:100})
                      .map(function(e,i){ // map each element to corresponding function call
                          return myFunction(i+1)
                      });
```